# Quarkus Keycloak Reactive - Keeps throwing BlockingNotAllowedException

Tags: java, keycloak, quarkus

I keep getting *org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.BlockingNotAllowedException* when using **quarkus-keycloak-admin-client-reactive** with other quarkus reactive components. I wonder what am I doing wrong.

I have written a simple code snippet:

```
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.json.bind.Jsonb;
import jakarta.json.bind.JsonbBuilder;
import jakarta.json.bind.JsonbConfig;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.HashMap;

@Path( "/hello" )
public class GreetingResource {

    @Inject
    Keycloak keycloak;

    @GET
    @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
    public Uni< Response > hello( ) {

        // Select the realm
        return Uni.createFrom( ).item( keycloak.realms( ).realm( "myRealm" ) )
                .flatMap( realmResource -> {

                    // Get the users resource
                    return Uni.createFrom( ).item( realmResource.users( ) )
                            .flatMap( users -> {

                                // Count all users in the realm
                                return Uni.createFrom( ).item( users.count( ) )
                                        .map( count -> {
                                            JsonbConfig jsonbConfig = ( new JsonbConfig( ) ).withNullValues( true ).withEncoding( StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name( ) );
                                            Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create( jsonbConfig );

                                            return Response.status( Response.Status.OK )
                                                    .entity( jsonb.toJson( new HashMap<>( ) {{
                                                        put( "count", count );
                                                    }} ) )
                                                    .build( );
                                        } );
                            } );
                } );
    }

}
```

I made sure that I have all keycloak calls through SmallRye's Uni. With all necessary configuration done on application.properties; here are my dependencies (Quarkus 3.7.3):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jsonb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-oidc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-oidc-token-propagation-reactive</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-keycloak-authorization</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jsonb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-keycloak-admin-client-reactive</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Am I doing the codes right?

Still I'm puzzled as to why the BlockingNotAllowedException is being thrown since all components are "reactive" (or at least they are label "reactive").

Some help here would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a sample application that exhibits the described behavior?

Comment: Not at the moment, but I can build a sample to produce this error. Would you like me to file a bug on this?

Comment: If you have an example application that reproduces the behavior, sure

Comment: The explanation of the issue and the repo to reproduce it is here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/38874. Thank you very much for the kind effort.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this more, this expected behavior.
The reason is that org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak only exposes a blocking API - which means that the implementation needs to block the current thread in order to provide the result in a blocking manner.

The only way around this would be if there were a non-blocking API version of the API